# Get output when username is asked on msysgit in Python (on windows)

Tags: python, git, io, msysgit

I'm trying to get the output when doing a git fetch, but it's halting asking for the user name and I'm unable to detect that.

I.e.: In a Python script I'm doing:

```
cmd = 'git fetch origin master'.split()
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, cwd='.',stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while p.poll() is None:
    r = p.stderr.read(1)
    print(r)
```

And it just halts without printing anything. If I ran it without piping stderr, the message asking for the username appears (so, it's writing but stderr.read does not detect anything).

```
[16:41:45 X:\]python test.py
Username for 'my.domain.com.br':
```

I've tried dealing with stderr.fileno() directly, changing the Popen bufsize, writing to the process.stdin, closing stdin and many different things to no avail. Anyone knows of a way to get that to work? (my feeling is that msysgit is just writing asking for the username without flushing or writing a new line and Python cannot deal with that properly, in which case it might only be fixed at msysgit? -- although it does appear in the shell if I don't pipe it, which is odd).

Context: I'm doing a program to help in dealing with multiple repositories at once (https://github.com/fabioz/mu-repo), so, as it can execute that for lots of repositories at once, not piping it is not really an option as too many things appear garbled (things do work if ssh access is specified or the password is already set through other means, but I'd like to have a way to say to users that the process is stuck waiting for input instead of just hanging there -- if there's a way to execute it making sure that git will fail if the password is asked, that'd suffice too).

Comment: Any particular reason you prefer to do this through shell commands rather than something like [Dulwich](http://www.samba.org/~jelmer/dulwich/docs/index.html) or [pygit2](https://github.com/libgit2/pygit2)?

Comment: One is simplicity (i.e.: no additional compiled library) and another is that by design many things I just repass as is to msysgit (so, it's just a matter of handling multiple processes and synchronizing the output), as I don't want to reinvent its command line, just have a proper way of dealing with multiple repos at once (as I'm not really fond of git-submodules nor mr).

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable, can't help with more but thought there would be no harm in confirming you considered and ruled out the other tools.

Answer (score 0):

Set up your global config for user name and email.  Then git will not prompt for these.

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your@email.address"
```

Comment: It won't prompt for the name, but it'll still prompt for the password... but that's not the point (as I said, it does work if things are properly configured, but if someone uses it when that's not properly configured, I want to be able to give proper feedback).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with subprocess.  When I run your code multiple times in my environment (Windows 7, no password needed for git), I get some but not all of the output, and each time I run it, I get a different amount of output.  To get around this, I ran the command and saved the output to a temp file, then read the file back, and I get all the output each time--something like this:

```
#!/bin/python
import os
import subprocess

cmd = "git fetch origin master"
filename = "temp.txt"

if os.name == "posix":
    p=subprocess.Popen(['sh', '-c', cmd+' >> '+filename])
elif os.name == "nt":
    p=subprocess.Popen(['cmd.exe', '/c '+cmd+' >> '+filename])
while not os.path.isfile(filename):
    pass
fd = open(filename, 'r')
return_value = None
out = ""
while return_value == None:
    text = fd.readline()
    if text:
        out += text
    return_value = p.poll()
while text:
    text = fd.readline()
    if text:
        out += text
fd.close()
```